# Find the prime factors of a number - wrong output

Tags: python-2.7

The code is given below:

```
n = input("Enter n: ")
f = 0
j = 2
for i in range(1, n/2 + 1):
  if n % i == 0:
    if i % j == 0:
      f = 1
      break
    if f ==0:
      print i ,
    j = j + 1
```

When I enter 21 as the input, I only get 1.

Can anyone correct my code ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode? That should help you find and fix the error yourself.

Comment: What did you expect `break` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
n = input("Enter n: ")
f = 0
j = 2
for i in range(1,n/2+1):
  if n%i == 0:
    for j in range(2,i/2+1):   #you need another loop to insure i has no factors
      if i%j == 0:
        f+=1

    if f==0:
      print i ,
  f = 0
```